# Freeing allocated memory causes the program to get stuck in Visual Studio but not in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, visual-studio, codeblocks

Let's say that I'm trying to read a string of unknown size at run time and print it:

```
int n = 0;
printf("Enter word size:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
char *str = (char*) malloc(n*sizeof(char));
if (str == NULL) {
    printf("Malloc failed\n");
    return 0;
}
printf("Enter string:\n");
char c;
int i = 0;
while (i < n&&scanf(" %c", &c) == 1) {
    str[i] = c;
    i++;
}
str[n] = '\0';
printf("Your string is: %s\n", str);
free(str);
```

When I try to run the program in CodeBlocks it runs fine, but when I try to run it in Visual Studio (2017) it gets stuck, if I comment out `free(str);` then it runs fine.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: You're not allocating enough memory for the null terminator, and you should look into how to use scanf with a limit in the format string. I'm sure Visual Studio gave you an error or showed an assert. It probably tells you what the problem is, but since you didn't include it...

Comment: Hint: crashing on `free` usually means you handled allocated memory incorrectly earlier in your code

Answer (score 1):

```
char *str = (char*) malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

but

```
str[n] = '\0';
```

you need to allocate 1 more :

```
char *str = (char*) malloc(n+1);
```

else you write after the allocated block with an undefined nehavior

Note by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1, so useless to multiply with it. The cast is also useless

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating enough space to account for the null-terminator in the string. An allocation of size `n` array will make the indices `0` to `n-1` valid locations to write to. Writing to `str[n]` causes heap corruption, which in turn causes the call to `free(str)` to be undefined behavior.

You need to allocate at least `n+1` bytes for a string containing `n` characters to account for the null terminator.

Comment: Why did this not cause any error when running it in CodeBlocks? i even tried to run it using an online compiler and it worked and didn't cause any problems.

Comment: @TitanEilabouni undefined behaviour means anything can happen. It may work; it may not. All bets are off.